# How can I divine the trick of multiplying $\sec x$ by $\dfrac{\tan(x)+\sec(x)}{\tan(x)+\sec(x)}$?

Tags: proof-explanation, indefinite-integrals

p. 464 Top of [*Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (6 edn 2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495011665) doesn't explain the discovery of  [this trick (in this question's title)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506783/53259), that thus feels clairvoyant.

I understand, but ask not about, other less tricky methods to calculate $\int \sec x \,dx $.

Comment: You can divine the trick by calculating $\int \sec x \, dx$ in one of those less tricky ways, and noticing that you get a logarithm. So the original integral must have secretly been of the form $\int \frac{du}{u}$.

Comment: @Micah: why write an answer in the "comment" box?

Comment: I wonder if knowing the identity $$ \tan\left( \frac x 2 + \frac \pi 4\right) = \tan x + \sec x, $$ combined with other things, might help here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You ought link to your [full answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2050080) that cites your paper. But how can you expect students to remember, or conjure up, $\tan\left( \frac x 2 + \frac \pi 4\right) = \tan x + \sec x,$? Even teachers wouldn't forebode to appeal to this little-known identity.

Answer (score 0):

As Micah suggested, use another method first, e.g. the frequently useful $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$. Then $\int\sec x dx=\int\frac{2dt}{1-t^2}=\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}+C$. But $$\frac{1+t}{1-t}=\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}.$$